# Working code in jsfiddle for jquery exact match

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, match

First I want to say that the code in jsfiddle works exactly as I'm expecting. However, when I try to insert it in my page, it does not work. 
I am using

```
 get.ajax
```

To move html with php a mysql data into a div named #latest-divs. I have a form with an

```
 input#search
```

button that gets
      val()
when 
     .bind('input property...)
 and checks if there is exact match in the child divs of `#latest-divs`. I call these child elements
     #latestblock
If there is exact match, then the event should execute, which, as I mentioned above, works in the jsfiddle but dies on my site. I have attempted everything I could think of:

Load in php file

Load from head

Load from body

Load with and without "CDATA"

Change my jquery version

My site is codefault (dot) org.
The jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/gAnyM/10/.
As of right now, I am loading the second part (random positioning of divs) from script/latest-topics.php and the first part in head, from index.php.

Comment: Please put a little bit more work into phrasing your questions in a way that can be understood by other people. Indentation/formatting is important, as is punctuation, spelling, and grammar (Though spelling and grammar is excusable, to a point - English isn't everyone's first language).

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you have it inside a:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  // code here
});
```

?

The dom needs to be ready before you bind things

jsfiddle adds this for you automatically

Comment: Yes as you can see my source code everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try another kind of event

```
$('input#search').bind('change keyup', function()
```